# How do you properly watch and reload Nginx conf?

Tags: nginx

I have two questions:

- Is there a difference between: `nginx -s reload` and `pkill -HUP -F nginx.pid`
- What's the simplest way to watch the Nginx conf file and upon changes test the conf file (`nginx -t`), and if it passes reload Nginx. Can that be done with `runit` or a process manager like Supervisor?

Comment: Is it `-F` or `-f` (I don't have `-F` on my `pkill`)

Comment: At least under Ubuntu 13.04 it's `-F` or `--pidfile`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least on Unix, both "reload" action and `HUP` signal are treated as one thanks to the declaration code

```
ngx_signal_t  signals[] = {
    { ngx_signal_value(NGX_RECONFIGURE_SIGNAL),
      "SIG" ngx_value(NGX_RECONFIGURE_SIGNAL),
      "reload",
      ngx_signal_handler },
```

in `src/os/unix/ngx_process.c`. In `ngx_signal_handler()` the same comnmon code

```
    case ngx_signal_value(NGX_RECONFIGURE_SIGNAL):
        ngx_reconfigure = 1;
        action = ", reconfiguring";
        break;
```

is executed, that prepares for a common reconfiguration.

To trigger an action when a file is modified, you could either make a [crontab](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/) and decide of a check-periodicity, or use [inotifywait](https://superuser.com/questions/181517/how-to-execute-a-command-whenever-a-file-changes).

To determine if `nginx -t` is in error, check the return code in a bash file, `$?`

```
nginx -t
if [ $? -eq 0 ] then;
    nginx -s reload
fi
```

Note: you may also use `service nginx reload`

(See return code check examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195607/bash-beginner-check-exit-status))

Comment: I actually usualy use `service nginx reload`

Comment: There is a typo, it should be `nginx -t`  instead of `linux -t` in the last code block. (can't change it because of silly "six characters needed for an edit" rule)

Answer (score 5):

```
#!/bin/bash

# NGINX WATCH DAEMON
#
# Author: Devonte
#
# Place file in root of nginx folder: /etc/nginx
# This will test your nginx config on any change and
# if there are no problems it will reload your configuration
# USAGE: sh nginx-watch.sh

# Set NGINX directory
# tar command already has the leading /
dir='etc/nginx'

# Get initial checksum values
checksum_initial=$(tar --strip-components=2 -C / -cf - $dir | md5sum | awk '{print $1}')
checksum_now=$checksum_initial

# Start nginx
nginx

# Daemon that checks the md5 sum of the directory
# ff the sums are different ( a file changed / added / deleted)
# the nginx configuration is tested and reloaded on success
while true
do
    checksum_now=$(tar --strip-components=2 -C / -cf - $dir | md5sum | awk '{print $1}')

    if [ $checksum_initial != $checksum_now ]; then
        echo '[ NGINX ] A configuration file changed. Reloading...'
        nginx -t && nginx -s reload;
    fi

    checksum_initial=$checksum_now

    sleep 2
done
```