# Check all commands exit code within a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, error-handling

Consider the case where I have a very long bash script with several commands. Is there a simple way to check the exit status for **ALL** of them easily. So if there's some failure I can show which command has failed and its return code.

I mean, I don't want to use the test **for each** one of them checks like the following:

```
my_command
if [ $status -ne 0 ]; then
    #error case
    echo "error while executing " my_command " ret code:" $?
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Is there a point of continuing once a command failed? Often than not tasks depend on each other.

Comment: No, I would like to stop the execution, cleanup and show a user friendly exit statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can test the value of `$?` or simply put `set -e` at the top of the script which will cause it to exit upon any command which errors.

```
#!/bin/sh

set -xe

my_command1

# never makes it here if my_command1 fails
my_command2
```

Comment: The way I program is to use `set -xe` for everything, and exit upon first error reporting all commands to the user. I updated the post to reflect this.

Comment: If you want to hard wire a command to not trigger the program to exit upon error while under `set -xe` use: bad_command || true

Answer (score 4):

You can do `trap "cmd" ERR`, which invokes `cmd` when a command fails. However this solution has a couple of drawbacks. For example, it does not catch a failure inside a pipe.

In a nutshell, you are better off doing your error management properly, on a case by case basis.

Comment: Is there some simple method in this case to show the failing command?

Answer (score 2):

You can write a function that launches:

```
function test {
    "$@"
    local status=$?
    if [ $status -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "error with $1" >&2
    fi
    return $status
}

test command1
test command2
```

Comment: this seems copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5195741/862225, no? If true, it would be nice to add a reference