# How to properly get return code of go build?

Tags: git, go, hook

I want to add `go build` into a precommit hook so that not to ship unbuildable code.

If the build succeeds, I want to continue commit, otherwise fail and reject commit.

How do I do it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any `pre-commit` hook will be executed by a git bash (even on Windows), so you can script it through a regular bash script.

See [Git Hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)

> Exiting non-zero from this hook aborts the commit, although you can bypass it with `git commit --no-verify`.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
go build
```

(from "[Checking Bash exit status of several commands efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5195826/6309)")
That way, you can chain multiple commands (like [`go vet`](https://golang.org/cmd/vet/), other [go linters](https://www.timeferret.com/lint)). If any of them fail, the `pre-commit` hook will prevent the commit.