# Capturing bash execution errors

Tags: bash

I want my bash scripts to detect execution errors and exit.

For the longest time I've been using the `try/yell/die` approach as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25515370/1267398).

```
yell() { echo "$0: $*" >&2; }
die() { echo -e "\e[31m$*\e[0m"; exit 1; }
try() { "$@" || die "cannot $*"; }
```

However this requires me to wrap my commands line this;

```
try curl https://blah.com | try bash
```

It seems the better approach would be to use;

```
set -e
set -o pipefail
set -E
```

Are there any downsides to using the `set` approach, opposed to `try/yell/die`?

Comment: See [Why doesn't set -e (or set -o errexit, or trap ERR) do what I expected?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) for some related discussion.

Comment: Thanks for the link @TomFenech, this should be an answer imho!

Answer (score 1):

See [Why doesn't set -e (or set -o errexit, or trap ERR) do what I expected?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) for some related discussion. – Tom Fenech

Answer (score 1):

FYI:

I use ...

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shout() { echo "$0: $*" >&2; }
die() { shout "${@:2} ($1)"; exit $1; }
try() { "$@" || die $? "cannot $*"; }
```

2 minor differences:

1. The exit code we eventually receive is the one that was generated by the command being tried.
2. The shout includes the exit code after the command in `(`, `)`.