# How to run program in Bash script for as long as other program runs in parallel?

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, timeout

I have two programs `server` and `client`. `server` terminates after an unknown duration. I want to run `client` in parallel to `server` (both from the same Bash script) and terminate `client` automatically a few seconds after the `server` has terminated (on its own).

How can achieve this?

I can [run multiple programs in parallel from a bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004811/how-do-you-run-multiple-programs-in-parallel-from-a-bash-script) and [timeout a command in Bash without unnecessary delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687948/timeout-a-command-in-bash-without-unnecessary-delay), but I don’t know the execution duration of server beforehand so I can’t simply define a timeout for client. The script should continue running so [exiting the script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378274/in-a-bash-script-how-can-i-exit-the-entire-script-if-a-certain-condition-occurs) to kill the child processes is not an option.

#### Edits

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004811/how-do-you-run-multiple-programs-in-parallel-from-a-bash-script) only addresses waiting for both processes to terminate naturally, not how to kill the `client` process once the `server` process has terminated.

@tripleee pointed to [this question on Unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/231676/given-two-background-commands-terminate-the-remaining-one-when-either-exits) in the comments, which works **especially if the order of termination is irrelevant.**

Comment: Use `wait` as explained in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3004814/7939871

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you run multiple programs in parallel from a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004811/how-do-you-run-multiple-programs-in-parallel-from-a-bash-script)

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/231676/given-two-background-commands-terminate-the-remaining-one-when-either-exits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

execProgram(){
  case $1 in
        server)
                sleep 5 &  # <-- change "sleep 5" to your server command.
                           # use "&" for background process    
                SERVER_PID=$!
                echo "server started with pid $SERVER_PID"
                ;;
        client)
                sleep 18 &  # <-- change "sleep 18" to your client command
                            # use "&" for background process
                CLIENT_PID=$!
                echo "client started with pid $CLIENT_PID"
                ;;
  esac
}

waitForServer(){
        echo "waiting for server"
        wait $SERVER_PID
        echo "server prog is done"

}

terminateClient(){
        echo "killing client pid $CLIENT_PID after 5 seconds"
        sleep 5
        kill -15 $CLIENT_PID >/dev/null 2>&1
        wait $CLIENT_PID >/dev/null 2>&1
        echo "client terminated"
}

execProgram server && execProgram client
waitForServer && terminateClient
```

Comment: You should never use `kill 9` routinely.

Comment: That’s exactly what I was looking for. Very smart to keep track of the PIDs. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With GNU Parallel you can do:

```
server() {
   sleep 3
   echo exit
}
client() {
   forever echo client running
}
export -f server client
# Keep client running for 5000 ms more
# then send TERM and wait 1000 ms
# then send KILL
parallel -u --termseq 0,5000,TERM,1000,KILL,1 --halt now,success=1 ::: server client
```